# python: Organizing object model of an application

Tags: python, oop

I have the following problem. My application randomly takes different  files, e.g. rar, zip, 7z. And I have different processors to extract and save them locally:

Now everything looks this way:

```
if extension == 'zip':
    archive = zipfile.ZipFile(file_contents)
    file_name = archive.namelist()[0]
    file_contents = ContentFile(archive.read(file_name))
elif extension == '7z':
    archive = py7zlib.Archive7z(file_contents)
    file_name = archive.getnames()[0]
    file_contents = ContentFile(
    archive.getmember(file_name).read())
elif extension == '...':
```

And I want to switch to more object oriented approach, with one main Processor  class and subclasses responsible for specific archives.

E.g. I was thinking about:

```
class Processor(object):

    def __init__(self, filename, contents):
        self.filename = filename
        self.contents = contents

    def get_extension(self):
        return self.filename.split(".")[-1]

    def process(self):
        raise NotImplemented("Need to implement something here")


class ZipProcessor(Processor):
    def process(self):
          archive = zipfile.ZipFile(file_contents)
          file_name = archive.namelist()[0]
          file_contents = ContentFile(archive.read(file_name))
```

etc

But I am not sure, that's a correct way. E.g. I can't invent a way to call needed processor based on the file extension, if following this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [rule of thumb](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0) is that if you have a class with two methods, one of which is `__init__()`, then it's not a class but a function is disguise.

Writing classes is overkill in this case, because you still have to *use* the correct class manually.

Since the handling of all kinds of archives will be subtly different, wrap each in a function;

```
def handle_zip(name):
    print name, 'is a zip file'
    return 'zip'

def handle_7z(name):
    print name, 'is a 7z file'
    return '7z'
```

Et cetera. Since functions are first-class objects in Python, you can use a dictionary using the extension as a key for calling the right function;

```
import os.path

filename = 'foo.zip'

dispatch = {'.zip': handle_zip, '.7z': handle_7z}
_, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
try:
    rv = dispatch[extension](filename)
except KeyError:
    print 'Unknown extension', extension
    rv = None
```

It is important to handle the `KeyError` here, since `dispatch` doesn't contain all possible extensions.

Answer (score 0):

An idea that might make sense before (or instead) of writing a custom class to perform your operations generally, is making sure you offer a consistent interface to archives - wrapping `zipfile.ZipFile` and `py7zlib.Archive7z` into classes with, for example, a `getfilenames` method.

This method ensures that you [don't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), without needing to "hide" your operations in a class, if you don't want to

You may want to use a [`abc`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html) as a base class, to make things extra clear.

Then, you can simply:

```
archive_extractors= {'zip':MyZipExtractor, '7z':My7zExtractor}
extractor= archive_extractors[extension]
file_name = extractor.getfilenames()[0]
#...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to OOP, you could give `Processor` a static method to decide if a class can handle a certain file, and implement it in every subclass. Then, if you need to unpack a file, use the base class'es [`__subclasses__()`](https://docs.python.org/release/2.6.4/library/stdtypes.html#class.__subclasses__) method to iterate over the subclasses and create an instance of the appropriate one:

```py
class Processor(object):
    @staticmethod
    def is_appropriate_for(name):
        raise NotImplemented()

    def process(self, name):
        raise NotImplemented()

class ZipProcessor(Processor):
    @staticmethod
    def is_appropriate_for(name):
        return name[-4:] == ".zip"

    def process(self, name):
        print ".. handling ", name

name = "test.zip"
handler = None

for cls in Processor.__subclasses__():
    if cls.is_appropriate_for(name):
        handler = cls()

print name, "handled by", handler
```